# allegro library 4.4 korean broken

Tags: c++, string, representation, allegro

I am working with allegro 4.4 library.

When I print a Korean character, the character is broken.

English character isn't in Allegro Manual.

Allegro says "Allegro uses UTF8 encoding by default."

I have no idea of what was wrong with the following code, and what to fix.

```
textout_ex(screen,font,"한글(korean)", 24, 2,
             makecol(255, 255, 255), -1);
```

Any idea of how to print Korean characters properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way does it break? Are you using a font that actually has those glyphs in it? Allegro has several ways of handling fonts; did you load Korean glyphs?

Comment: "한글(korean)" represented like "^^^(korean)" thanks for you help

Comment: Have you tried directly constructing the string from bytes (rather than using a string literal)? It is possible that your compiler does not support unicode string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you did not load a font that has Korean glyphs. Alternatively, the Allegro loading functions simply didn't load the Korean glyphs from the font file. So first check the font to see if it has the glyphs you need, then check Allegro's documentation to see how to make it load them.

Note: just because a library says that it supports strings of UTF-8 or 16 encoding does not mean that they actually support all of those glyphs. And it *certainly* doesn't mean that they support complex text layout. I don't know if Korean requires complex text layout, but Allegro certainly doesn't support it.

Comment: thank you very much! the manual(allegro manual 4.2) says use TTF2PCX program to make pcx. I made a pcx file from korean font(which has korean glyphs) but same representation. and I also tried addon allegTTF but I have no luck. allegTTF's example says load_ttf_font function is what I have to use but it makes linking error "unresolved external symbol" help~